# How to solve: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'get_offset_position'

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I try to test a simple Plotly examaple but I run into this error.
My code is just this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly.tools import mpl_to_plotly

mpl_fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[23, 12, 34])
plotly_fig = mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)
plotly_fig
```

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [/mpl-to-plotly-limitations](https://community.plotly.com/t/mpl-to-plotly-limitations/14686).  It's really not supported or maintained.  I'd recommend going straight to **plotly** with the data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly.tools import mpl_to_plotly
import plotly.express as px

# mpl_fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# ax.scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[23, 12, 34])
# plotly_fig = mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)
# # plotly_fig

px.scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[23, 12, 34])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used this example from a, recent, book. Seems not to be very accurate.